# How do I omit blank cells when giving range/reference to another function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was building this flashcard generator for learning German language in Excel.
What I do is I enter a number of words in a column.

I pick up random entries from the list using the INDEX() function and try and answer them.

```
=INDEX(Array,RANDBETWEEN(1,<no. of entries in column>),1)
```

For the "Array", I drag my mouse from the first entry in the column to the last entry.

There are multiple lists covering nouns, adjectives, verbs and so on.

But, whenever I add more vocabulary to the lists, I have manually edit the array to include those new entries.

I visualised giving the entire column as array, and 'somehow' select only the non-blank values in the column. So that whenever I add an entry to the list, it is automatically included in the flashcard generation.

Any ideas about this 'somehow' would be much appreciated.

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OjPfMYL6eA1A3El43knA2UtZIrdfQnka/view?usp=sharing) is what it looks like as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the entire column as an array and count the number of entries to determine the maximum possible value to index:

```
=INDEX(A:A,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(A:A)),1)
```

Comment: I..was almost there haha. Will have to begin the lists at column 1 though.

Comment: You just need to change `A:A` for the column you want to use,.

Comment: ah, i meant row 1 xD

Comment: You could just have the random number generated between the row that your data starts at and the end of the data. no need to actually move your data

Comment: @LafaMan yeah. works either way. had them in separate sheets so moving wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic named range for your array so that way when you add new elements to it, they will automatically get included.

Then in your formula, replace "Array" with the named range

```
=INDEX(DynamicName,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(DynamicName)),1)
```

Comment: didn't know a lot about dynamic ranges. seem pretty useful.